# How to get wordpress source code of theme in php

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a site which is designed in wordpress. I have evrything that wordpress gives.like admin name password.database.But i dont have the admins password by which i change the setting in wordpress theme.is there anyway to get the theme's source code that my site has.I like to change the site without entering admins panel.i like to change it using only code is there any way to do that.I will appreciate any help.

Comment: ftp to the wp-content/themes/your_theme_name?

Comment: where that theme is present on my server???

Comment: if the theme is installed and selected then you can just develop on a local install and upload and overwrite the theme on your server without needing the admin panel at all yes. I would imagine it is in the (www) public_html/[your wordpress site]/wp-content/themes/[your theme name] directory of your server

Comment: Do you have the FTP password?

Comment: If you have your database password, login to your database, change the password of your admin. Login to admin dashboard, and change your theme files. Other way, you connect with FTP, download your theme files, edit it locally and re-upload them replacing existing ones.

Comment: my admin password is not working thats why i wont be able to enter into dashbord.but i have database,and code file..is there any way to reset it??like from database.where admin password is saved of dashbord???cause i wont find it on wp_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your dashboard, look on the left side panel and choose **appearance > editor**. Once there, look to the right of your screen and choose which part of the site you'd like to edit (posts, stylesheet, etc). This is where you can do changes.

I think this is what you were asking for.

Comment: I wont be able to enter into dashboard cause i dont know admins password thats why i want to edit the site with source code...?

Comment: You're starting to sound very dodgy =) - if you have access to the Database, change the admin password field in `wp_users`